# Dynamically referencing a cell

Tags: excel, parameters, excel-formula, filepath

I would like to set up Names for the drive, file path, Excel spreadsheet name and sheet name in cells in Excel, and then concatenate them together when referencing external cells.  This will allow me to create macros that reference sheets dynamically in the sense that it does not matter where the spreadsheet is.

So far, I have the following:

> Drive = C
>   Location = Users\ashleys\Desktop\New Quote Production\Quote Location 3\Ash
>   Name = Book3
>   Sheet = Sheet1

(Please note that the = sign above can be read as "assigned Name as")

I concatenate these together to create another Name (called Final) in the following fashion:

> Final = "'"&Drive&":\"&Location&"["&Name&".xlsx]"&Sheet&"'!"

Final resolves to be the following:

```
C:\Users\ashleys\Desktop\New Quote Production\Quote Location 3\Ash\[Book3.xlsx]Sheet1'!
```

So, as far as I am concerned, so far so good!

However, I am embarrassingly stumbling at the last hurdle.  when I use the Final defined Name in cell references, it does not resolve in the way I expect.  So, if I am in Book1 and I use the code above to refer to cell A3 (which for example contains the word "Success!") in Book3, I would hope that typing the following into a cell in Book1 would resolve to "Success!":
=Full&A3

Instead, the A3 resolves to A3 in Book1.

Comment: If you are trying to code this you need to show your code (working or not).

Comment: Hi Jeeped,  I thought I did by showing the "'"&Drive&":\"&Location&"["&Name&".xlsx]"&Sheet&"'!".  There's no VBA behind this I'm afraid.  Just simple Excel concatenation and Cell referencing.  I know there is a VBA solution, but I was not trying this at this point.

Comment: OK, then the `vba` and `excel-vba` tags were misleading. Don't throw mud at a wall to see what sticks; it just obfuscates the issue at hand. You probably need the [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) but that doesn't work on closed, external workbooks.

Comment: To get it to work you'd need to wrap the string cell location in the INDIRECT function, but the other workbook would have to be open.

Comment: Hi Jeeped - I don't know whether to thank you, or be a bit annoyed at your response.  I made it clear I was very new and one of the reasons I cringe and worry when accessing the knowledge of experts in forums like this is because the responses can be quite snarky.  However, you are indeed providing free advice and that can't be ignored.  So thank you.  I will research the INDIRECT function and see how I get on.

Comment: Thanks Darren - that is likely to be the missing link.  I had trouble coming up with an intelligent Google search for this.  Your response is appreciated.

Comment: Jeeped and Darren - I have tried this and it worked.  Thank you very much indeed for your responses.  As you may have guessed, I am a new starter in the realm of VBA and Excel formulae and your assistance has helped me expand my knowledge.

Comment: @Mandelbrot1987 - No worries and welcome to [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). This site is a little different and has a prescribed mandate of working toward a definitive collection of answers to programming problems (yes, Excel formulas are programming!). It can take a little getting used to the first time around.

Comment: Just for future reference if you want people to get a notification that you've written a new comment you need to add an @ symbol in front of their names.  Otherwise the only way they'll see your new comment is if they happen to come back to the question.  I'm not attempting to be snarky in telling you this letting you know so you don't think people are ignoring you.

Comment: @Jeeped - I was going to delete the comment as  you'd given the same answer a couple of seconds earlier - I'll add it as an answer though.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook thanks for that.  Happy to accept the answer from either of you.  Merci!

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook  I see the text "Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer, or simply pay it forward by providing a great answer to someone else's question."  Lesson learned! :)

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use INDIRECT for that to work, but the other workbook would have to be open.

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm

As the workbook has to be open for it to work there's no need to add the file location to the string.  It may be useful in some VBA code used in the Workbook open event to automatically open the other workbook though, or look at Excel workspaces to open the other files.

http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/save-as-workspace.htm

i.e. `=INDIRECT("'[Book3.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1")` or `=INDIRECT(Final)` if Final is a named value.